# how can I get the same result of leptonica's pixReduceRankBinary2 and pixCloseBrick on openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, leptonica

I am translating a go program that uses leptonica library to a python script that uses openCV, and I cant find a way to translate the following:

```
img = pixReduceRankBinary2(img, 2, NULL);
img = pixReduceRankBinary2(img, 2, NULL);
img = pixCloseBrick(NULL, img, 2, 3);
```

is there an implementation of those functions in openCV?

Comment: What do those functions do? Is there some reference?

Comment: From https://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/binreduce_8c_source.html it looks like it takes a binary image and downsamples by 2 using a 2x2 moving window that tests how many of the 4 pixels are white at the higher resolution. The user can choose the number that should be white (or higher) to make the output white at the 1 lower resolution pixel for the 2x2 neighborhood at the higher level.

Comment: So you might do that by getting the mean at every pixels using a 2x2 moving window mean (just a -blur box filter of size 2x2), since the count in a 2x2 region is just mean\*width\*height = 2\*2\*mean = 4\*mean. Then decimate using Numpy slicing to skip every other pixel.

Comment: @fmw42, thanks, I will try to understand better what you mean :), thanks again for your time

Comment: See also Skimage `downscale_local_mean` at scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/…. So once you have the mean from that function, you can just threshold it (at 25%, 50%, 75% or 100% of 255). Or you can specify a count threshold (1,2,3,4) and convert it to the threshold of the mean as mean_threshold = 255*(25/100)*count_threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do that using Python/OpenCV/Skimage. Simply read the image and ensure it is binary. The use Skimage downscale_local_mean to downsample by 2 using 2x2 neighborhoods producing a factor of two smaller image whose values are the means of the 2x2 neighborhoods. Then threshold again in 25% increments to correspond to leptonica counts for their pixReduceRankBinary2 function.

Input (rice grains):

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.transform

# read image
img = cv2.imread('rice_bw.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold to binary
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# decimate by factor of 2 to mean values in 2x2 regions
decimate = skimage.transform.downscale_local_mean(thresh, (2,2))

# set count to 1,2,3 or 4
count=2

# convert count to percent of 255 in increments of 25%
count_thresh = 255 * (25/100) * count

# threshold again
result = cv2.threshold(decimate, count_thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("rice_bw_binary_decimate.png", result)

# show result
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result for count=2:

[image]

Comment: this is great!, thanks, I really appreciate your time